# Boxplot in R comparing two data frames

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to make a boxplot R. I have two loaded data frames- both of which have a column titled MEANS. I am trying to create a box and whiskers plot comparing both of the columns titled MEANS for both of these data frames in preparation to run an ANOVA. What is the most straight forward way to do this?

Comment: *I have two loaded data frames* ... please [share the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451). *I am trying* ... please share your attempted code and any issues (i.e., errors, undesired results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would combine the two data frames into a single dataframe, then plot:

```
df1 <- data.frame(data = rep("data1",100),MEANS = rnorm(100))
df2 <- data.frame(data = rep("data2",100),MEANS = rnorm(100))

df <- rbind(df1,df2)

boxplot(data = df, MEANS ~ data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

if the object names are 'df1', 'df2', then load this into a `list`, extract the column and apply `boxplot`

```
lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:2)), function(x) boxplot(x$MEANS))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!